# I am trying to make a delete button on phonebook app with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

'I'm new to this site and at the same time to react j . I have the code to create the phonebook app .'
`````
function App() {
const [entries, setEntries] = useState(entries_data);

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("application:", JSON.stringify(entries, null, 2));

    return () => console.log("App is re-rendering!");
  });

  const addEntry = entry => {
    setEntries(entries => [...entries, entry]);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Phone Book</h1>
      <PhoneBookForm addEntry={addEntry} />
      <InformationTable entries={entries} />
    </section>
  );
}

const initiateEntry = {
  Name: "",
  phone: ""
};
```

```
'The application should contain two fields for entering name and phone number, an add button, a field where the entered data will be displayed.'
```

```
        function PhoneBookForm({ addEntry }) {
      const [entry, setEntry] = useState(initiateEntry);
    
      useEffect(() => console.log("Form is rendering"));
    
      const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addEntry(entry);
      };
    
      const handleChange = e => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
    
        setEntry(entry => ({ ...entry, [name]: value }));
    
        console.log({ name, value });
      };
    
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={style.form.container}>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <br />
          <input
            style={style.form.inputs}
            name="Name"
            type="text"
            value={entry.Name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <br />
         
          <label>Phone:</label>
          <br />
          <input
            style={style.form.inputs}
            className="userPhone"
            name="phone"
            type="text"
            value={entry.phone}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input style={style.form.submitBtn} type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
        </form>
      );
    }
```

'Now I can't add a delete button that would delete the added contacts. Can someone help me, how should that function look like?'

```
function InformationTable({ entries }) {
  return (
    <>
      <table style={style.table} className="informationTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={style.tableCell}>Name</th>
            <th style={style.tableCell}>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {!entries.length && <p>No data :( </p>}
          {entries.map(entry => (
            <PhoneBookEntry entry={entry} key={entry.Name} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <input style={style.form.deleteBtn} type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </>
  );
}

function PhoneBookEntry({ entry }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{entry.Name}</td>
      <td>{entry.phone}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in the following way:

1. First of all, send to `PhoneBookEntry` A contact `deleteEntry` function that takes an argument of the contact's `index` number in your `entries` array

```
{entries.map((entry, index) => (
   <PhoneBookEntry entry={entry} key={entry.Name} deleteEntry={() => deleteEntry(index)} />
))}
```

2. Add a delete button to each contact in the `PhoneBookEntry`
   component

```
function PhoneBookEntry({ entry, deleteEntry }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{entry.Name}</td>
      <td>{entry.phone}</td>
      <td><button onClick={deleteEntry}>delete entry</button></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

3. Add the `deleteEntry` function itself in the `App` component

```
  const deleteEntry = index => {
    setEntries(entries => entries.splice(index, 1)); // remove the index item from array
  };
```

4. Then of course send the `deleteEntry` function to `InformationTable`

```
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Phone Book</h1>
      <PhoneBookForm addEntry={addEntry} />
      <InformationTable entries={entries} deleteEntry={deleteEntry} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

5. And finally, extract the `deleteEntry` function in the `InformationTable`

```
    function InformationTable({ entries, deleteEntry }) {
```

Comment: @Sanja I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as an answer that helped you and give me the score please :)

Comment: I've never done this before, so I hope I done it right :)) Thanks again

Comment: You did it great, if this is your first time then you should always know how to do it next time, this is to help the community and people who will read the question

Comment: @Sanja You can also raise and lower reputation for a user's answer or question with the arrows that appear next to the question (there are a number between them)